# How to log message while registering a ServiceProvide in Laravel?

Tags: logging, laravel, monolog, service-provider

So I have a Laravel service provider and I would like to create a DEBUG log entry when it is applied:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register() {
        Log::debug('message'); //fails, Log facade alias isn't available yet
        $this->app['log']->debug('message'); //fails too
    }
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: This is probably not be the _best_ solution, but you could register your `MyServiceProvider` after your other service providers are available.  For instance, at the bottom of `app/start/global.php`  `App::register('MyServiceProvider');`.

Comment: Actions that "rely on another service provider already being registered" (e.g. Laravel logging system) are not meant to be performed from the `register` method, but only from the `boot` method, as stated in [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#service-providers). That said, I'm waiting for workarounds! P.S: Doesn't Laravel itself log each service provider being registered? Maybe just a logging detail level to be configured...

Comment: Are you tried to change the sort order initialization of providers?

Comment: Ho to do that? Is there a way to append the service provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel, service providers is defined in `app/config/app.php`

It will fail if MyServiceProvider present early before `LogServiceProvider`, because `LogServiceProvider` has not registered yet. on the opposite side, If MyServiceProvider show later, It's exactly the answer you want.

For more details, [ProviderRepository](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php) have responsibility for register the application service providers.

```php
<?php
return array(
    'providers' => array(
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider', // Log facade is registered here.
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
        'MyServiceProvider', // You have to put this after LogServiceProvider.
    )
);
```